# Trouble with SQLite query in android

Tags: android, sqlite, inner-join

I have a listView with two viewTypes. For the first viewType I get data from one SQLite table, and for others - from another table. I am using inner join to join these two tables like this:

```
static {
        sProfileWithHobbiesBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        sProfileWithNewsBuilder.setTables(
                UsersInfoEntry.TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN " +
                        HobbiesEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ON " +
                        HobbiesEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + HobbiesEntry.USER_ID + " = " +
                        UsersInfoEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + UsersInfoEntry.USER_ID);
    }
```

All works fine, but...
if the second table is empty, getColumnCounts return 0 and then nothing is shown...
And if I need the next result: if the second table is empty, just show info for the first viewType...

I will be glad any ideas to fix this question!

Comment: What about a `LEFT JOIN` or am I missing something?

Comment: @ci_ you mean just replace INNER JOIN with LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Yeah, does that not work?

Comment: Might be `LEFT OUTER JOIN` , there is even an example here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#setTables(java.lang.String)

Comment: @ci_ will try in a minnute

Comment: @ci cool :)
it works! if you wand, post your answer as separated answer and I will mark it as correct answer ;-)
thanks again!

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of the `INNER JOIN`. A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will keep the columns from the first table even if the second table cannot be joined on the specified join columns (because there is no matching record).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#setTables(java.lang.String) even shows an example of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.